# What resources do threads compete for other than CPU and memory

Tags: java, multithreading

In the book [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://jcip.net/) by Brian Goetz et al.:

*If a thread pool is too big, then threads compete for scarce CPU and memory resources, resulting in higher memory usage and possible resource exhaustion. If it is too small, throughput suffers as processors go unused despite available work.*

This means that if we have too many thread objects created in the thread pool, then they can consume too much memory. Also, if we have too many threads (e.g. 1000 threads for 10 CPU cores, with 1000 tasks submitted to the thread pool), then each task will be assigned to a core but may be pre empted before it completes, and another task will then be assigned to the core. So the tasks may each individually take a very long time to complete due to pre emptive scheduling.

Are there other resources that the threads are competing for?

Comment: This is impossible to answer. It depends entirely on what the threads are doing: if they’re accessing a database, then they compete for that, if they access disk/network/some synchronized block of code/anything else, they’ll compete for those. If you can name a resource you could compete for, someone can write threads that compete for it.

Comment: but since we have 10 cores, only 10 threads will be accessing the database at any given time (even if we have 1000 threads in the pool), so why does having more threads make any difference for that database access?

Comment: You can be running more threads than cores. The CPU can dedicate a bit of time to one, then some time to another, etc. If those ‘bits of time’ don’t sync up (note: they won’t) then you can have far more active database connections than you have cores.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure in case of Java thread-stacks, but under Linux if memory is allocated, it is initialized with the shared zero-page. And no page frame (physical memory) is actually used. Only when a thread want to write to a zero page, there is a page fault and a page frame is actually allocated (copy on write).

So if a thread doesn't use much of its stack, it should consume very little memory. Of course in worst case, every thread could consume all of its stack and hence consume a lot of memory.

If you have CPU intensive tasks, then probably you don't want to have more tasks than CPU cores. Otherwise you will be wasting time on the consequences of context switching (including cold caches), TLB misses etc.

About the resources: there are too many too mention.

Answer (score 0):

Threads can be considered as competing for cache resources, if a cache is shared by threads and pushes out old cache entries to make space for new entries (which is the typical case).

If there are caches with configured maximum sizes, each entry in a cache that the thread benefits from (an entry that helps it save time by being present in the cache) is an entry that a different thread can't use. Ideally, threads use similar cache entries, and the threads cooperate with others by helpfully preloading resources for each other. But if threads do not use similar cache entries, and especially when the cache is small, a thread adding entries to the cache will have to remove old entries from the cache, which will tend to be entries used by other threads that have not executed recently. In the extreme case, there can be *cache thrashing*: when a thread runs it pushes out *all* the entries used by other threads, so that whenever a thread resumes execution it finds that the shared cache has *no* entries that benefit it. And such cache thrashing is particularly bad if the penalty for a *cache miss* is high.

The most important example of this problem are the memory caches, especially the smaller faster cache (L1).

If the filesystem uses hard disks for storage, the position of the disk arm is like a one entry cache that has a very large penalty for a cache miss: I've seen a case where a multithreaded filesystem scanner (think of the Unix `find` program) could not achieve the performance of a single threaded scanner because of disk thrashing.